pronunciation of wrist
I was watching the world championship snooker on television. Several times the commentators said things like "Great shot with the wrist" or "Kyren Wilson is strong with the wrist". Every time they pronounced "wrist" as "wrest". Why? Dialect? It makes me wonder how they would pronounce a sentence like: The wrestler broke his wrist.

It is not "wrist" it is "rest".  In snooker, the "rest" is a stick that you can place your cue on to reach balls that would not be playable otherwise. It has  cross shaped metal end.  Here is a picture.

Professional players will never use the rest if it can be avoided. They can get much better control if they rest the cue on their hand.

See, for example https://youtu.be/5KA-tqDHPx4?si=WsY2GgtAczjIMIg3

Thank you. This is a great answer, and it explains a lot. I am not sure though that it explains everything. I have not noticed a correlation between the use of the rest and the above mentioned commentary. Today I payed extra attention to this. John Virgo made two such comments, one indeed after the rest was used, but the other wasn't. Tomorrow I will watch the final again.

It may be that there are some times when Virgo says "wrist", but because you are primed to hear "rest" you mishear.  Virgo has an accent (Lancashire) but it isn't strong, and i->e isn't a particular feature of that dialect.
